# Does the iPhone, when connected to a portrait display with a 16:9 ratio, utilize the entire screen?

Tags: iphone, display

Assuming the use of the lightning to digital AV adaptor connected to a modern 16:9 1080p display rotated to portrait.

The iPad clearly does window boxing regardless, but I’ve only been able to find images of the iPhone connected to displays in landscape mode.

Comment: Why not test it? I can’t for you as I don’t have the specific items you mention.

Comment: I’m not sure which monitors do support portrait input.